# Trying to filter AccessList = %%1537 in event viewer :/

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-event-log, eventviewer, xml

I've got file auditing enabled and I'd like to be able to filter for a given user action. I have set up an XML filter that's pretty basic, but I can't seem to get it to  work. I've got it working with a couple of eventdata categories other than AccessList such as HandleId and SubjectUserName.

```
<QueryList> 
 <Query Id="0" Path="Security"> 
  <Select Path="Security"> 
   *[EventData[Data[@Name='AccessList'] and (Data='%%1537')]] 
  </Select> 
 </Query> 
</QueryList>
```

I'm trying to find the following:

```
<Event>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="AccessList">%%1537</Data>
 </EventData>
</Event>
```

Can anyone offer some guidance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `&#xD;&#xA;&#x09;&#x09;&#x09;&#x09;` after `%%1537`

`&#x09;` -- the Tab

`&#xA;` -- newline

`&#xD;` -- carriage return

```
<QueryList> 
 <Query Id="0" Path="Security"> 
  <Select Path="Security"> 
   *[EventData[Data[@Name='AccessList'] and (Data='%%1537&#xD;&#xA;&#x09;&#x09;&#x09;&#x09;')]] 
  </Select> 
 </Query> 
</QueryList>
```

Reference: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/bd136cf0-fb9e-48a1-ae2f-3cd4290ab973/issue-with-custom-build-xml-query-in-event-viewer?forum=winserverpowershell

Comment: I'm only 8 months late. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use hex value instead of schema value,

```
Eg. %%1537 = 0x10000
```

So the query will be,

```
<QueryList> 
 <Query Id="0" Path="Security"> 
  <Select Path="Security"> 
   *[EventData[Data[@Name='AccessList'] and (Data='0x10000')]] 
  </Select> 
 </Query> 
</QueryList>
```

Comment: Source: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/event-4663